# How to check auto scale activity in progress prior to auto scale in AWS Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I use AWS Java SDK to autoscale ec2 instances. Following is the code snippet.

```
AmazonAutoScaling client = AmazonAutoScalingClientBuilder.standard().build();
SetDesiredCapacityRequest request = new SetDesiredCapacityRequest().withAutoScalingGroupName("my-auto-scaling-group").withDesiredCapacity(2)
        .withHonorCooldown(true);
SetDesiredCapacityResult response = client.setDesiredCapacity(request);
```

I have set **withHonorCooldown()** as true. It means that subsequent auto scale requests are blocked until AWS launched the Ec2 instance. So my use case is, I have triggered 100 autoscale requests to AWS concurrently due to this most of the requests are failed. So my requirement is to check whether there is currently activities in progress in a particular AWS autoscale group.

```
if(!client.isAutoscaleInprogress())
    client.setDesiredCapacity(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isScalingActivityInProgress(){
AmazonAutoScaling client = AmazonAutoScalingClientBuilder.standard().build();
DescribeScalingActivitiesRequest request = new DescribeScalingActivitiesRequest().withAutoScalingGroupName("my-auto-scaling-group");
        DescribeScalingActivitiesResult response = client .describeScalingActivities(request);
 Activity activity=response.getActivities().get(0);
 return !ScalingActivityStatusCode.Successful.name().equalsIgnoreCase(activity.getStatusCode()
}
```

**Note:** activity.[getStatusCode()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/autoscaling/model/ScalingActivityStatusCode.html#InProgress) returns the current activity status of the autoscale group.